# Run portable app with autoit--compiled

Tags: autoit, portable-executable

Hi i want to know how to make a portable app to run in an autoit gui. what commands/functions to use so when i compile the gui script and the portable app i want the portable app runs in the gui. an example would be great.
thanks

Comment: You are going to have to explain that better. Give us an example of what portable app, show what code you have so far, show what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The exe file you create with Autoit can be copied to any win32 system and you will be able to run. If that's what you meant under portable that's the answer.

You can't make android app or anything alike with autoit it is not java it is not cros splatform it is a windows automation tool moreover a programming language in itself but for windows systems only